# tensorflowjs converter throws 'dtype int64 not supported'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I want to convert a saved_model using the tensorflowjs converter. I am using tensorflowjs==0.6.5 and tensorflow==1.12.0 due to some backwards compatibility constraints.

But I am getting the following error:

```
  File ".../.pyenv5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflowjs/write_weights.py", 
    line 290, in _assert_valid_weight_entry
    data.dtype.name + ' not supported.')
  ValueError: Error dumping weight module_apply_default/Encoder_en
      /KonaTransformer/ClipToMaxLength/Const, 
  dtype int64 not supported.
```

The command I am using is:

```
tensorflowjs_converter 
  --input_format=tf_saved_model \
  --output_node_names='label1/predictions/probabilities' \
  --saved_model_tags=serve \
  /Users/macuser/Desktop/models-master/experiments/tf_tfjs_local_model/20/1555947164 \
  model1
```

How can I compile the saved model in this setup correctly?